# How to pass jQuery ajax custom header in CORS call to .NET Core Web Api app?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

In a .NET Core 1.1 Web Api app CORS is enabled to accept requests from a specific URL/domain and accept headers.

```
  services.AddCors(options =>
  {
    options.AddPolicy("CORS_LocalHost", builder => builder
    .WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000")
    .WithHeaders("accept", "content-type", "origin", "app-key")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    );
  });
```

An AJAX request is initiated from another .NET Core Web App using jQuery .ajax() with a custom "app-key" header defined in the "headers".

```
var request = $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://localhost:5050/resources/category/1',
  cache: false,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: { 'app-key': 'testapikey' }
});
```

and the request is successfully received by the Web Api domain and processed using custom middleware like this

```
if (!httpContext.Request.Headers.Any(h => h.Key == APPKEY_HEADER))
```

to determine if the custom "app-key" header is present. However, the custom "app-key" header is not one of the nine(9) headers in the request

[image]

I've also tried

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('app-key', 'testapikey');},
```

w/ the same results.

Is there a jQuery ajax option that needs to be set or something in the .NET Core Web Api project?

NOTE: This endpoint has been tested successfully w/ Postman.

Comment: I've also tried options.AllowAnyHeader() and the app-key header isn't present.

Comment: Did you ever got this to work? If so, could you post and share solution?